# Adding Additional Codecs to Chromium Build (outside of chromium-codecs-ffmpeg)

Tags: html5-video, chromium, codec

I am trying to add additional codec support to Chromium for HTML5 media play back. I've installed the package chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extras to include a few more than what is included in original download.

I am curious if anyone knows the amount of work/ if its possible to fork the chromium code and add additional codec supports (.ts, .avi, etcc). Is it as simple as forcing chromium to use a different ffmpeg library or possibly use VLC to decode all of its videos?